# Ability to customize keycloak error format

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

When I do a POST call that looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://${my.domain.com}/auth/realms/${myrealm}/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: 4e8d8b81-5e5d-e868-79ec-33d6a37238af'
```

I have a response from keycloak like this:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type"
}
```

That's expected behavior, but I want to customize response to my custom structure, like this:

```
{
    errors: [{
       "field": "grant_type",
       "description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type"
    }]
}
```

or some other structure. Is it possible to do this in some way?

Keycloak returns response in this format cause they have a such mapping in `KeycloakErrorHandler.java`

I'm trying to override this code with my custom handler:

```
@Provider
public class KeycloakErrorDtoHandler extends KeycloakErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(KeycloakErrorDtoHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable throwable) {
        // my logic
    }
    ...
}
```

but I have had no success.

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?